# Ubuntu 18.04 open-vm-tools broken package

Tags: 18.04, package-management, error-handling

When I try to upgrade apt it says `open-vm-tools` kept back but when I try to upgrade specifically it occurs error saying dependency fail. Full error process given below. For any additional information please ask to resolve my issue.

```
ripon@ripon:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  open-vm-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
ripon@ripon:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade open-vm-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 open-vm-tools-desktop : Depends: open-vm-tools (= 2:11.0.1-2ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 2:11.0.5-4ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                         Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

`apt-cache` details given in addition below

```
ripon@ripon:~$ apt-cache policy open-vm-tools-desktop open-vm-tools
open-vm-tools-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     2:11.0.1-2ubuntu0.18.04.2 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
open-vm-tools:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:11.0.5-4ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
     2:11.0.5-4ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:10.2.0-3ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: `apt-cache policy  open-vm-tools-desktop open-vm-tools` please; package `xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse `is according to package search only available in xenial.

Comment: @nobody done please check now.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` why is a package hold back, even it is not on your system? `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii'`